# I am using JQUERY Lightbox I Help me to solve Simple Issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I am using JQUERY Lightbox, There is one close button by default I just want do disable other close option like if I click anywhere on display screen it also close my Light box. I just want that when I click on Close Button it close otherwise it remain open. Full code available here https://code.google.com/p/jquery-lightbox/source/browse/trunk/jquery.lightbox.js?r=2

```
$.fn.lightbox.defaults = {
    showInfo:false,
    adminBarHeight:0, //28
    overlayOpacity: 0.8,
    borderSize: 10,
    imageArray: new Array,
    activeImage: null,
    inprogress: false, //this is an internal state variable. don't touch.
    widthCurrent: 250,
    heightCurrent: 250,
    xScale: 1,
    yScale: 1,
    displayTitle: true,       
    imageClickClose: false,
    followScroll: false,
    isIE8: false  //toyNN:internal value only
};  
$(document).ready(doLightBox);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has following line

```
$overlay.click(function(e) { closeLightbox(); e.preventDefault; });
```

change that line with following line of code.

```
$overlay.click(function(e) { e.preventDefault; });
```

Reference :  [link](http://techjam.gr/2011/web-design/prevent-lightbox-closing-clicking/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#overlay").click(function(){ $.fn.lightbox.end(); }).hide();
```

change this code to below code

```
$("#overlay").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault; });
```

try this code